# how to check xmlnode for innertext or value in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I created xmlnodelist and i want to handle the value of elements that dont have childs.
at the following code i'm checking for childnodes and i get true from all of the elements, even
those without childs.
how can i pick the last elements in the tree and handle the value's?

```
XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XDoc.Load("d://avi.xml");
            XmlNodeList XList = XDoc.SelectNodes("//*");
            foreach (XmlElement XNode in XList)
            {
                    if (XNode.HasChildNodes == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("this node has childs");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else Console.WriteLine("this node dont have childs");      
            } 


<level1>
    <level2>
        <level3>header3</level3>
        <level4>another</level4>
        <level31>header31</level31>
    </level2>
    <level2>
        <level3>111</level3>
        <level31>nn</level31>
    </level2>
</level1>
```

Comment: Side note: please avoid use of capital casing for variable names in publicly shared C# code as it is not recommended in C# coding guidelines and a lot of people will read something like `XList` as some sort of type name and be confused for a while... may discourage people to looks at your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using Linq to Xml for this?

```
var xElem = XElement.Parse(xml);

var leafElements = xElem.Descendants()
                        .Where(e => !e.HasElements)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was hoping to avoid use od linq since i'm not femiliar with subject yet.

Comment: @user1701492 Fair enough... but do you think reading above code is hard?

Answer (score 1):

The text within an element is a "node" as well.  What you want is

```
if (XNode.ChildNodes.Any(n=>n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
```

Alternatively you can loop through the ChildNodes and see if one of them is an element.

Comment: nodes with childs are also elemens so looping through them doesnt help.